# Mapping an Oracle data type to a C# property type

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, orm

When creating a property to correspond to an Oracle column of type NUMBER(6, 3), what factors should I consider before deciding what data type to make the corresponding property (a Double, a Float, or...???)

IOW, with this Oracle column definition:

```
PercentageOfCodersWhoCobbleCobol     NUMBER (6, 3)
```

...I currently have a corresponding property like this:

```
private Double percentageOfCodersWhoCobbleCobol;

public double PercentageOfCodersWhoCobbleCobol
        {
            get
            {
                return this.percentageOfCodersWhoCobbleCobol;
            }
            set
            {
                this.percentageOfCodersWhoCobbleCobol = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("PercentageOfCodersWhoCobbleCobol");
            }
        }
```

...but should the property be float or something else instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store only 6 digits, so `float` should be enough. [The type `float` has a precision of 7 digits.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691146%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

However, if you would like to do some arithmetics (multiplication, division) with these numbers, and write the result back to database, than you should consider using `double`. Moreover, if these values store numbers entered by humans (e.g. amount of money) than `decimal` may be required.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this stack overflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583150/c-oracle-data-type-equivalence-with-oracledbtype) as reference. For your question, I think it    should be mapped to double not float.