# Login Stored Procedure in Oracle | Error: PLS-00306

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, sqldatasource

I'm calling a stored procedure in a package from an ASP.NET SqlDataSource however I keep getting the following error.

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'VALIDATE_USER_PRC'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

My Stored procedure looks like:

```
PROCEDURE VALIDATE_USER_PRC(P_APPLICATIONNAME IN TBL_USERS.APPLICATIONNAME%TYPE,
P_USERNAME IN TBL_USERS.USERNAME%TYPE,
P_PASSWORD IN TBL_USERS.USERPASSWORD%TYPE,
P_RESULTS OUT NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO P_RESULTS FROM TBL_USERS WHERE USERNAME=P_USERNAME
AND (USERPASSWORD=P_PASSWORD)
AND APPLICATIONNAME=P_APPLICATIONNAME;
END VALIDATE_USER_PRC;
```

It's declared in my package PARENT_USER_API.

- TBL_USERS.APPLICATIONNAME%TYPE = **VARCHAR2(255)**
- TBL_USERS.USERNAME%TYPE = **VARCHAR2(255)**
- TBL_USERS.USERPASSWORD%TYPE = **VARCHAR2(128)**

Finally my ASP.NET code looks as such:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsLogin" runat="server" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false"
   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
   ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
   SelectCommand="PARENT_USER_API.VALIDATE_USER_PRC" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
   <SelectParameters>     
      <asp:Parameter Name="P_APPLICATIONNAME" DefaultValue="/PortailParent" Type="String" />
      <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtUser" Name="P_USERNAME" PropertyName="Text"  Type="String" />
      <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtPass" Name="P_USERPASSWORD" PropertyName="Text"  Type="String" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="P_RESULTS" Direction="Output" Type="Int32" />
   </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My reasoning for using **R_RESULTS** is to see if any rows are returned with the given username and password in order to validate the user who's trying to login.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've searched for hours and tried several things with no luck as of yet. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

Embarrassingly the answer to my issue was in the `SelectParameters` of my `SqlDataSource`.

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtPass" Name="P_USERPASSWORD" 
     PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
```

The name I provided was `P_USERPASSWORD` instead of simply `P_PASSWORD`.

Evidently I forgot to change it after switching my `SqlDataSource` which was iniatally programmed with my select statement in the `SelectCommand` to it's stored procedure counterpart.

Answer (score 1):

if your `"P_RESULTS"` is an `int32` field, try to change the type of the out parameter to OracleDbType.Int32.

I hope it works.

Check this post. [C#: Oracle Data Type Equivalence with OracleDbType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583150/c-oracle-data-type-equivalence-with-oracledbtype)

Comment: I've tried DbType already with no luck either. I've also tried using Decimal and Double. Thanks for the quick response though!

Comment: Have you seen this? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleDbTypeEnumerationType.htm

Comment: Yep, I took a look at it when you posted it earlier, however changing to Decimal, Double or any other numeric type didn't fix the problem unfortunately

Comment: The name of the procedure shown in the error log is different of the procedure you posted. Are you sure you are calling the correct procedure?

Comment: Oops, sorry about that, I was testing with another method, but no, it still doesn't work when calling VALIDATE_USER_PRC.