# OracleManagedDataAccess does not retrive strings from stored procedure parameter

Tags: c#, oracle, enterprise-library, odp.net

Sorry if my English is not as good as I hope :D.
Im using VS2013 and downloaded ODP.NET via Nuget Package. 
Im calling a method in a sp in a Oracle db. I have been able to stablish the connection, but when Im trying to get the string value from the output parameter, this one comes null. The int values retrieves ok but not the strings.
Im calling this method with the same values ej. employeeNumber = 431206 and companyNumber = 0

Here is my web config file connstring

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="OracleMOC"
     connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (COMMUNITY = uri.world) (PROTOCOL = TCP) (Host = 14.85.65.12) (Port = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SID = SIOX)));User Id=***;Password=****;"
     providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
```

And my code

```
 public Employee GetEmployeeByNumber(string employeeNumber, int companyNumber)
    {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleMOC"].ToString());
            con.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "SPR.GetEmployeeDetail";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("I_FEC_APROY", OracleDbType.Date, DateTime.Now, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("I_FICHA", OracleDbType.Int32, Convert.ToInt32(employeeNumber.Trim()), ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("I_EMPCLAVE", OracleDbType.Int32, companyNumber, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("O_RC", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50000, ParameterDirection.InputOutput);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("O_PLAZA", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("O_NIVEL", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("O_NIVEL_P", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("O_CENTRO", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("O_DEPTO", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("O_DDEPTO", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50000, ParameterDirection.InputOutput);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("O_AEMP", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("O_DEMP", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("O_FEC_RPROY", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50000, ParameterDirection.InputOutput);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("O_VALIDO", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("O_FICHA", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("O_NOMBRE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("O_APPAT", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("O_APMAT", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("O_ORGANISMO", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("O_NUMFAM", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("O_DESC_ORG", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            employee.EmployeeNumber = employeeNumber;
            employee.CompanyNumber = companyNumber;
            employee.Regime = cmd.Parameters["O_RC"].Value.ToString();
            employee.Plaza = cmd.Parameters["O_PLAZA"].Value.ToString();
            employee.Level = cmd.Parameters["O_NIVEL"].Value.ToString();
            employee.Level_P = cmd.Parameters["O_NIVEL_P"].Value.ToString();
            employee.CenterNumber = cmd.Parameters["O_CENTRO"].Value.ToString() == "null" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["O_CENTRO"].Value.ToString());
            employee.DepartmentNumber = cmd.Parameters["O_DEPTO"].Value.ToString() == "null" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["O_DEPTO"].Value.ToString());
            employee.DepartmentDescription = cmd.Parameters["O_DDEPTO"].Value.ToString();
            employee.EmployeeYear = cmd.Parameters["O_AEMP"].Value.ToString() == "null" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["O_AEMP"].Value.ToString());
            employee.EmployeeDay = cmd.Parameters["O_DEMP"].Value.ToString() == "null" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["O_DEMP"].Value.ToString());
            employee.FirstName = cmd.Parameters["O_NOMBRE"].Value.ToString();
            employee.LastName = cmd.Parameters["O_APPAT"].Value.ToString();
            employee.LastName2 = cmd.Parameters["O_APMAT"].Value.ToString();

            employee.Organism = cmd.Parameters["O_ORGANISMO"].Value.ToString();

            if (cmd.Parameters["O_VALIDO"].Value.ToString() == "null")
                employee.IsValid = false;
            else
            {
                if (cmd.Parameters["O_VALIDO"].Value.ToString() == "true")
                {
                    employee.IsValid = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    employee.IsValid = true;
                }
            }

            employee.DateFinish = cmd.Parameters["O_FEC_RPROY"].Value.ToString();
            employee.OrganismDescription = cmd.Parameters["O_DESC_ORG"].Value.ToString();
            con.Close();

        return employee;

    }
```

I tested the same sp but using Enterprise Library with the same provider.

```
public Employee GetEmployeeByNumber(string employeeNumber, int companyNumber)
    {            
        Employee employee = null;
        try
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeNumber))
            {                    
                EmployeeDataSet ds = new EmployeeDataSet();
                DatabaseProviderFactory dbProviderFactory = new DatabaseProviderFactory();
                Database db = dbProviderFactory.Create("OracleMOC");

                DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("SPR.GetEmployeeDetail");
                db.AddInParameter(cmd, "I_FEC_APROY", DbType.DateTime, DateTime.Now);
                db.AddInParameter(cmd, "I_FICHA", DbType.Int32, Convert.ToInt32(employeeNumber.Trim()));
                db.AddInParameter(cmd, "I_EMPCLAVE", DbType.Int32, companyNumber);
                db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "O_RC", DbType.String, 200);
                db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "O_PLAZA", DbType.String, 200);
                db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "O_NIVEL", DbType.Int32, 100);
                db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "O_NIVEL_P", DbType.Int32, 100);
                db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "O_CENTRO", DbType.Int32, 200);
                db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "O_DEPTO", DbType.Int32, 200);
                db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "O_DDEPTO", DbType.String, 200);
                db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "O_AEMP", DbType.Int32, 200);
                db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "O_DEMP", DbType.Int32, 200);
                db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "O_FEC_RPROY", DbType.DateTime, 200);
                db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "O_VALIDO", DbType.Int32, 200);
                db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "O_FICHA", DbType.Int32, 200);
                db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "O_NOMBRE", DbType.String, 200);
                db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "O_APPAT", DbType.String, 200);
                db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "O_APMAT", DbType.String, 200);
                db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "O_ORGANISMO", DbType.Int32, 200);
                db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "O_NUMFAM", DbType.Int32, 200);
                db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "O_DESC_ORG", DbType.String, 200);

                db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "O_NOMBRE").ToString()) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "O_APPAT").ToString()))
                {
                    return employee;
                }
                else
                {
                    employee = new Employee();
                }
                employee.EmployeeNumber = employeeNumber;
                employee.CompanyNumber = companyNumber;
                employee.Plaza = db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "O_PLAZA").ToString();
                employee.Level = db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "O_NIVEL").ToString();
                employee.Level_P = db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "O_NIVEL_P").ToString();
                employee.CenterNumber = db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "O_CENTRO") == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "O_CENTRO"));
                employee.DepartmentNumber = db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "O_DEPTO") == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "O_DEPTO"));
                employee.DepartmentDescription = db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "O_DDEPTO").ToString();
                employee.EmployeeYear = db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "O_AEMP") == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "O_AEMP"));
                employee.EmployeeDay = db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "O_DEMP") == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "O_DEMP"));
                employee.FirstName = db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "O_NOMBRE").ToString();
                employee.LastName = db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "O_APPAT").ToString();
                employee.LastName2 = db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "O_APMAT").ToString();
                employee.Regime = db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "O_RC").ToString();
                employee.Organism = db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "O_ORGANISMO").ToString();
                employee.IsValid = db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "O_VALIDO") == DBNull.Value ? false : !Convert.ToBoolean(db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "O_VALIDO"));
                employee.DateFinish = db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "O_FEC_RPROY").ToString();
                employee.OrganismDescription = db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "O_DESC_ORG").ToString();
            }
            return employee;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }           
    }
```

Unfortunately I dont have a 10 of reputation to post images.

**The big question is, why the ODP.NET Works fine with Enterprise Library, but not with the native code which supposedly is better. Am I doing something wrong?**

Comment: A couple of things stand out.  I believe you need to specify a size for output parameters, and I don't think there is such a thing as a 50k varchar2.

Comment: :D Thanks for your reply. Even if I use 50k size or not using, still have the same result null. As I wrote, Im not able to publish images. The parameter that Im testing is te O_PLAZA that comes null

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with Mananged ODP.NET but in older ODP:NET you have to specify the max. length of return value, i.e. it should be like this:

```
myOracleCmd.Parameters.Add("O_APMAT", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
myOracleCmd.Parameters["O_APMAT"].Size = 1000;
```

Or you can write it in a single line:

```
myOracleCmd.Parameters.Add("O_APMAT", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 1000, null, ParameterDirection.Output);
```

Then perhaps you also have to specify the `DbType` of parameter, i.e.

```
cmyOracleCmdmd.Parameters["O_APMAT"].DbType = DbType.String;
```

Here you see a list of DbType vs. OracleDbType: [C#: Oracle Data Type Equivalence with OracleDbType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583150/c-oracle-data-type-equivalence-with-oracledbtype)

Then a general note: your SP contains a lot of output parameters, maybe it is shorter to return just a single RefCursor and read out the attributes from this cursor instead of defining each output parameter one-by-one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried as you told without luck :(

Comment: :D I know there is a lot of out parameters in the SP , unfortunately I cant modify that SP.. I have to use it as is right now.