# How to execute function using oracle C# windows application

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, stored-functions

Need Help! I am new in executing function in a stored procedure package, I need to execute this package using oracle C# windows application..

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TSCBE1005_PKG IS

FUNCTION TSCBE1005_001_FNC( P_BLD_LVL_CD         IN VARCHAR2,
                            P_IN_DATE            IN VARCHAR2,
                            P_IN_PC              IN VARCHAR2,
                            P_BLD_SPEC_NO        IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                            P_BLD_SPEC_NO_SEQ    IN OUT NUMBER,
                            P_ART_NO             IN OUT VARCHAR2`,
                            P_CURE_KIBN          IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                            P_CURE_LR_KBN        IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                            P_HINMEI             IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                            P_TIRE_SIZE          IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                            P_E4_MARK            IN OUT NUMBER,
                            P_SECTOR_NO          IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                            P_UPLATE_NO          IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                            P_LPLATE_NO          IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                            P_BLADER_NO          IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                            P_MAX_TCLC_SINGLE    IN OUT NUMBER,
                            P_TCLC_UNIT_SINGLE   IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                            P_MAX_IP_SINGLE      IN OUT NUMBER,
                            P_IP_UNIT_SINGLE     IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                            P_PR                 IN OUT NUMBER,
                            P_MSG                IN OUT VARCHAR2
                            ) RETURN NUMBER;

PROCEDURE TSCBE1005_002_PRC( P_RET_DATA           IN NUMBER,
                             P_INFO1              IN VARCHAR2,
                             P_INFO2              IN VARCHAR2,
                             P_IN_PC              IN VARCHAR2
                             ) ;
END TSCBE1005_PKG;
```

When I'm running it to Oracle, using script below, it's actually successful.

```
variable O_BLD_SPEC_NO        VARCHAR2(7)
variable O_BLD_SPEC_NO_SEQ    NUMBER
variable O_ART_NO             VARCHAR2(5)
variable O_CURE_KIBN          VARCHAR2(4)
variable O_CURE_LR_KBN        VARCHAR2(1)
variable O_HINMEI             VARCHAR2(50)
variable O_TIRE_SIZE          VARCHAR2(20)
variable O_E4_MARK            NUMBER
variable O_SECTOR_NO          VARCHAR2(6)
variable O_UPLATE_NO          VARCHAR2(6)
variable O_LPLATE_NO          VARCHAR2(6)
variable O_BLADER_NO          VARCHAR2(7)
variable O_MAX_TCLC_SINGLE    NUMBER
variable O_TCLC_UNIT_SINGLE   VARCHAR2(3)
variable O_MAX_IO_SINGLE      NUMBER
variable O_IO_UNIT_SINGLE     VARCHAR2(3)
variable O_PR                 NUMBER
variable O_MSG                VARCHAR2(20)
variable ret                  varchar2(100)

execute :ret := TSCBE1005_PKG.TSCBE1005_001_FNC('R123456789','20170124120644','YRC07400',:O_BLD_SPEC_NO,:O_BLD_SPEC_NO_SEQ,:O_ART_NO,:O_CURE_KIBN,:O_CURE_LR_KBN,:O_HINMEI,:O_TIRE_SIZE,:O_E4_MARK,:O_SECTOR_NO,:O_UPLATE_NO,:O_LPLATE_NO,:O_BLADER_NO,:O_MAX_TCLC_SINGLE,:O_TCLC_UNIT_SINGLE,:O_MAX_IO_SINGLE,:O_IO_UNIT_SINGLE,:O_PR,:O_MSG)
;
print O_BLD_SPEC_NO      
print O_BLD_SPEC_NO_SEQ  
print O_ART_NO           
print O_CURE_KIBN        
print O_CURE_LR_KBN      
print O_HINMEI           
print O_TIRE_SIZE        
print O_E4_MARK          
print O_SECTOR_NO        
print O_UPLATE_NO        
print O_LPLATE_NO        
print O_BLADER_NO        
print O_MAX_TCLC_SINGLE  
print O_TCLC_UNIT_SINGLE 
print O_MAX_IO_SINGLE    
print O_IO_UNIT_SINGLE   
print O_PR               
print O_MSG              
print ret
```

I tried to execute this in C# oracle using below code,

```
        using (OracleConnection objConn = new OracleConnection("User    id=skraze; Password=skraze; Data source=database"))
        {
            objConn.Open();

            OracleCommand objCmd = new OracleCommand();
            objCmd.Connection = objConn;
            objCmd.CommandText = "TSCBE1005_PKG.TSCBE1005_001_FNC";
            objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            OracleParameter P_BLD_LVL_CD = new OracleParameter();
            P_BLD_LVL_CD.ParameterName = ":P_BLD_LVL_CD";
            P_BLD_LVL_CD.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            P_BLD_LVL_CD.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            P_BLD_LVL_CD.Value = "R123456789";
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(P_BLD_LVL_CD);

            OracleParameter P_IN_DATE = new OracleParameter();
            P_IN_DATE.ParameterName = ":P_IN_DATE";
            P_IN_DATE.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            P_IN_DATE.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            P_IN_DATE.Value = "20170124120644";
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(P_IN_DATE);


            OracleParameter P_IN_PC = new OracleParameter();
            P_IN_PC.ParameterName = ":P_IN_PC";
            P_IN_PC.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            P_IN_PC.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            P_IN_PC.Value = "YRC07400";
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(P_IN_PC);

            OracleParameter P_BLD_SPEC_NO = new OracleParameter();
            P_BLD_SPEC_NO.ParameterName = ":P_BLD_SPEC_NO";
            P_BLD_SPEC_NO.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            P_BLD_SPEC_NO.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(P_BLD_SPEC_NO);

            OracleParameter P_BLD_SPEC_NO_SEQ = new OracleParameter();
            P_BLD_SPEC_NO_SEQ.ParameterName = ":P_BLD_SPEC_NO_SEQ";
            P_BLD_SPEC_NO_SEQ.OracleType = OracleType.Number;
            P_BLD_SPEC_NO_SEQ.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(P_BLD_SPEC_NO_SEQ);

            OracleParameter P_ART_NO = new OracleParameter();
            P_ART_NO.ParameterName = ":P_ART_NO";
            P_ART_NO.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            P_ART_NO.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(P_ART_NO);

            OracleParameter P_CURE_KIBN = new OracleParameter();
            P_CURE_KIBN.ParameterName = ":P_CURE_KIBN";
            P_CURE_KIBN.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            P_CURE_KIBN.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(P_CURE_KIBN);

            OracleParameter P_CURE_LR_KBN = new OracleParameter();
            P_CURE_LR_KBN.ParameterName = ":P_CURE_LR_KBN";
            P_CURE_LR_KBN.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            P_CURE_LR_KBN.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(P_CURE_LR_KBN);

            OracleParameter P_HINMEI = new OracleParameter();
            P_HINMEI.ParameterName = ":P_HINMEI";
            P_HINMEI.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            P_HINMEI.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(P_HINMEI);


            OracleParameter P_TIRE_SIZE = new OracleParameter();
            P_TIRE_SIZE.ParameterName = ":P_TIRE_SIZE";
            P_TIRE_SIZE.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            P_TIRE_SIZE.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(P_TIRE_SIZE);

            OracleParameter P_E4_MARK = new OracleParameter();
            P_E4_MARK.ParameterName = ":P_E4_MARK";
            P_E4_MARK.OracleType = OracleType.Number;
            P_E4_MARK.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(P_E4_MARK);


            OracleParameter P_SECTOR_NO = new OracleParameter();
            P_SECTOR_NO.ParameterName = ":P_SECTOR_NO";
            P_SECTOR_NO.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            P_SECTOR_NO.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(P_SECTOR_NO);


            OracleParameter P_UPLATE_NO = new OracleParameter();
            P_UPLATE_NO.ParameterName = ":P_UPLATE_NO";
            P_UPLATE_NO.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            P_UPLATE_NO.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(P_UPLATE_NO);

            OracleParameter P_LPLATE_NO = new OracleParameter();
            P_LPLATE_NO.ParameterName = ":P_LPLATE_NO";
            P_LPLATE_NO.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            P_LPLATE_NO.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(P_LPLATE_NO);

            OracleParameter P_BLADER_NO = new OracleParameter();
            P_BLADER_NO.ParameterName = ":P_BLADER_NO";
            P_BLADER_NO.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            P_BLADER_NO.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(P_BLADER_NO);

            OracleParameter P_MAX_TCLC_SINGLE = new OracleParameter();
            P_MAX_TCLC_SINGLE.ParameterName = ":P_MAX_TCLC_SINGLE";
            P_MAX_TCLC_SINGLE.OracleType = OracleType.Number;
            P_MAX_TCLC_SINGLE.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(P_MAX_TCLC_SINGLE);

            OracleParameter P_TCLC_UNIT_SINGLE = new OracleParameter();
            P_TCLC_UNIT_SINGLE.ParameterName = ":P_TCLC_UNIT_SINGLE";
            P_TCLC_UNIT_SINGLE.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            P_TCLC_UNIT_SINGLE.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(P_TCLC_UNIT_SINGLE);

            OracleParameter P_MAX_IO_SINGLE = new OracleParameter();
            P_MAX_IO_SINGLE.ParameterName = ":P_MAX_IO_SINGLE";
            P_MAX_IO_SINGLE.OracleType = OracleType.Number;
            P_MAX_IO_SINGLE.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(P_MAX_IO_SINGLE);

            OracleParameter P_IO_UNIT_SINGLE = new OracleParameter();
            P_IO_UNIT_SINGLE.ParameterName= ":P_IO_UNIT_SINGLE";
            P_IO_UNIT_SINGLE.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            P_IO_UNIT_SINGLE.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(P_IO_UNIT_SINGLE);

            OracleParameter P_PR = new OracleParameter();
            P_PR.ParameterName = ":P_PR";
            P_PR.OracleType = OracleType.Number;
            P_PR.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(P_PR);



            OracleParameter W_BLD_SPEC_NO = new OracleParameter();
            W_BLD_SPEC_NO.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            W_BLD_SPEC_NO.Size = 7;
            W_BLD_SPEC_NO.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(W_BLD_SPEC_NO);

            OracleParameter W_BLD_SPEC_NO_SEQ = new OracleParameter();
            W_BLD_SPEC_NO_SEQ.OracleType = OracleType.Number;
            W_BLD_SPEC_NO_SEQ.Size = 1;
            W_BLD_SPEC_NO_SEQ.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(W_BLD_SPEC_NO_SEQ);

            OracleParameter W_ART_NO = new OracleParameter();
            W_ART_NO.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            W_ART_NO.Size = 5;
            W_ART_NO.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(W_ART_NO);

            OracleParameter W_CURE_KIBN = new OracleParameter();
            W_CURE_KIBN.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            W_CURE_KIBN.Size = 4;
            W_CURE_KIBN.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(W_CURE_KIBN);

            OracleParameter W_CURE_LR_KBN = new OracleParameter();
            W_CURE_LR_KBN.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            W_CURE_LR_KBN.Size = 1;
            W_CURE_LR_KBN.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(W_CURE_LR_KBN);

            OracleParameter W_HINMEI = new OracleParameter();
            W_HINMEI.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            W_HINMEI.Size = 50;
            W_HINMEI.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(W_HINMEI);

            OracleParameter W_TIRE_SIZE = new OracleParameter();
            W_TIRE_SIZE.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            W_TIRE_SIZE.Size = 20;
            W_TIRE_SIZE.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(W_TIRE_SIZE);

            OracleParameter W_E4_MARK = new OracleParameter();
            W_E4_MARK.OracleType = OracleType.Number;
            W_E4_MARK.Size = 1;
            W_E4_MARK.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(W_E4_MARK);

            OracleParameter W_SECTOR_NO = new OracleParameter();
            W_SECTOR_NO.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            W_SECTOR_NO.Size = 6;
            W_SECTOR_NO.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(W_SECTOR_NO);

            OracleParameter W_UPLATE_NO = new OracleParameter();
            W_UPLATE_NO.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            W_UPLATE_NO.Size = 6;
            W_UPLATE_NO.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(W_UPLATE_NO);

            OracleParameter W_LPLATE_NO = new OracleParameter();
            W_LPLATE_NO.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            W_LPLATE_NO.Size = 6;
            W_LPLATE_NO.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(W_LPLATE_NO);

            OracleParameter W_BLADER_NO = new OracleParameter();
            W_BLADER_NO.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            W_BLADER_NO.Size = 7;
            W_BLADER_NO.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(W_BLADER_NO);

            OracleParameter W_MAX_TCLC_SINGLE = new OracleParameter();
            W_MAX_TCLC_SINGLE.OracleType = OracleType.Number;
            W_MAX_TCLC_SINGLE.Size = 1;
            W_MAX_TCLC_SINGLE.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(W_MAX_TCLC_SINGLE);

            OracleParameter W_TCLC_UNIT_SINGLE = new OracleParameter();
            W_TCLC_UNIT_SINGLE.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            W_TCLC_UNIT_SINGLE.Size = 3;
            W_TCLC_UNIT_SINGLE.Direction =     ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(W_TCLC_UNIT_SINGLE);

            OracleParameter W_MAX_IO_SINGLE = new OracleParameter();
            W_MAX_IO_SINGLE.OracleType = OracleType.Number;
            W_MAX_IO_SINGLE.Size = 1;
            W_MAX_IO_SINGLE.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(W_MAX_IO_SINGLE);

            OracleParameter W_IO_UNIT_SINGLE = new OracleParameter();
            W_IO_UNIT_SINGLE.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            W_IO_UNIT_SINGLE.Size = 3;
            W_IO_UNIT_SINGLE.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(W_IO_UNIT_SINGLE);

            OracleParameter W_PR = new OracleParameter();
            W_PR.OracleType = OracleType.Number;
            W_PR.Size = 1;
            W_PR.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(W_PR);


            objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            objConn.Close();

        }
```

But I'm still getting error

```
{"ORA-06550: line 1, column 34:\nPLS-00103: Encountered the symbol \"=\" when expecting one of the following:\n\n   . ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod not rem\n   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like\n   between || indicator\n"}
```

Please, I hope anyone could help me :(

Comment: This is a vast and unwieldy example. It is unreasonable of you to expect us to wade through all that. I suggest you try a smaller example (say a procedure which takes one parameter) and make that work. Then start on the bigger stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This looks wrong

```
P_BLD_LVL_CD.ParameterName = ":P_BLD_LVL_CD";
                              ^
```

The colon is used for identifying placeholders in a SQL string. Actual parameter name should be

```
P_BLD_LVL_CD.ParameterName = "P_BLD_LVL_CD";
```

Also `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue` is used for the return value only. So there should only be one such parameter per function call. You appear to be using it for all the IN OUT parameters. That is wrong.

For IN OUT parameters you need to use `ParameterDirection.InputOutput`.

Incidentally a function with IN OUT parameters is poor PL/SQL practice, but I guess there's not much you can do about that.

So, `TSCBE1005_001_FNC` is a function which takes three IN (read only) parameters and eighteen IN OUT (read/write) parameters. Therefore your call needs:

- one parameter with `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`
- three parameters with `ParameterDirection.Input`
- eighteen parameters with `ParameterDirection.InputOutput`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help :) I really appreciate it. I have another question,, you said "one parameter with ParameterDirection.ReturnValue".. with all my fields, the return value should only be this one--> variable ret    varchar2(100)??? sorry, this is really my first time to execute a stored procedure in C#..

Comment: Hi sir, could you help me, what is the right approach how to execute the stored procedure using C# application? in our practice, we are using oracle data client. is there a ways to apply this using oracle data client?

Answer (score 0):

I never used `objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`

I always use this syntax:

```
objCmd.CommandText = "BEGIN :res := TSCBE1005_PKG.TSCBE1005_001_FNC(:P_BLD_LVL_CD, :P_IN_DATE, ...); END;";
objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

Then your parameter declaration is wrong.

```
P_SECTOR_NO.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
```

ParameterDirection has to match signature of your function, i.e. `ReturnValue` or `Input` or `Output` (not used in your example) or `InputOutput`

The type is also wrong:

```
P_SECTOR_NO.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
```

You must use OracleDbType, see [OracleDbType Enumeration](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleDbTypeEnumerationType.htm). For mapping between OracleDbType and .NET type see [C#: Oracle Data Type Equivalence with OracleDbType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583150/c-oracle-data-type-equivalence-with-oracledbtype#1583197)

btw, you can put this all in one command, e.g.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("P_BLD_LVL_CD", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = "R035570412";
```

Be aware in case of `ParameterDirection.Output` you have to set `DbType` separately. Also in case of `OracleDbType.Varchar2` you must specify the size and an initial value:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("parName", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 240, null, ParameterDirection.Output);
cmd.Parameters("parName").DbType = DbType.String;
```

Comment: Hello Wernfried, thank you for taking the time to take a look at my problem, I really appreciate it. So, you mean, I can also use this as CommandText --------------> execute :ret := TSCBE1005_PKG.TSCBE1005_001_FNC('R035570412','20170124120644','YRC07400',:O_BLD_SPEC_NO,:O_BLD_SPEC_NO_SEQ,:O_ART_NO,:O_CURE_KIBN,:O_CURE_LR_KBN,:O_HINMEI,:O_TIRE_SIZE,:O_E4_MARK,:O_SECTOR_NO,:O_UPLATE_NO,:O_LPLATE_NO,:O_BLADER_NO,:O_MAX_TCLC_SINGLE,:O_TCLC_UNIT_SINGLE,:O_MAX_IO_SINGLE,:O_IO_UNIT_SINGLE,:O_PR,:O_MSG)??????

Comment: Hi sir, is this function may be applicable in Oracle data client?