# What is the correct Oracle Data Type to .Net mapping for NUMBER(4,0)?

Tags: sql, .net, oracle

I am using the [`OracleDataReader` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader?view=netframework-4.8).

When I run `GetInt32(index)` for `NUMBER(8,0)`, it works well, but when I use  the same code for `NUMBER(4,0)`, I get an error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll

I hope to have explained my problem well. Thanks in advance.

By the way, I have already checked [Oracle Data Type Mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/oracle-data-type-mappings)

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583150/c-oracle-data-type-equivalence-with-oracledbtype

Comment: The document refers to `System.Data.OracleClient` (which is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/oracle-and-adonet?view=netframework-4.8)), it might be different to `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client`